# Application's packets in the middle of TCP paylod

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

I think normally HTTP packets are expected at the beginning of TCP payload. Is it possible to have HTTP packets starting in the middle of TCP payload?

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, if HTTP keepalive is in force, or tunneled requests (which is really batching, very poorly named feature: several requests are sent before any response is read).